# Delete Middle Node in Python [from a purely C background]

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list, nodes

I have been playing around with Python more recently due to its power and syntax. I've decided to make a linked list from https://www.tutorialspoint.com but with my strong background in C and being use to its manual memory allocation as well as having pointers for one the delete middle function is somewhat confusing to me. I know that objects makes references to other objects and variables and that the Python interpreter automatically handles this:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class SLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def printlist(self):
        cur = self.head
        while cur is not None:
            print(cur.data)
            cur = cur.next
    def insertAtHead(self, newdata):
        NewNode = Node(newdata) #create new node

        newNode.next = self.head #create its .next to point to the current node

        self.head = newNode #set its .next to point the current head
#creates a linked list with 3 elements
    def createOneTwoThree(self):
        list = SLinkedList()
        list.head = Node('Mon')
        e2 = Node('Tues')
        e3 = Node('Wed')

        list.head.next = e2
        e2.next = e3
#function to add at the end of a linked list
    def insertAtEnd(self, newdata):
        newNode = Node(newdata)#create new node
        if self.head = newNode:#if empty insert the thing
            self.head = newNode
            return
        laste = self.head
        while(last.next):
            last = last.next
        last.next = newNode


    def inBetween(self, middle_node,newdata):
        if middle_node is None:
            print('Error 0: The mentioned node is absent')
            return

            newNode = Node(newdata)
            newNode.next = middle_node.next
            middle_node.next = newNode
   def delete(self, removeKey):

       headVal = self.head

       if(head  is not None):
           if (head.data == removeKey):
               break
            prev = head
            head = None

        while(head is not None):
            if head.data == removeKey:
                break
            prev = head
            head = head.next

        if (head == None):
            return
        prev.next = head.next

        head = None

#Link Firt node to second node: list1.head.next = n2*******
```

I just fail to see what's going on here from a memory point of view that justifies it finding the in-between two said values and having them linked together. I am still new to Python and its classes and structures but from an intuitive aspect the inBetween method makes little sense to me though I see it's most underlying logic. Can someone more versed in Python please explain to my WHY this is happening and what exactly is going on with the objects, references and pointers?

Comment: your code is !c.

Comment: https://rushter.com/blog/python-garbage-collector/

Comment: Unlike in C where identifiers or l-values *are* objects, in Python the identifiers or l-values are **never** objects themselves.

Comment: You can think of **all** python names to be C pointers with implicit reference.

Comment: BTW there is incorrect indentation in `inBetween`. Also, could you possibly trim down the example and make it somewhat clearer what exactly it is that you're having problem with?

Comment: When you link the node into the list, python increments the reference counter (of the node). When you unlink the node from the list, python decrements the reference counter, and when this counter reaches 0, python deletes(`free`s) it from memory.

Comment: Not a proper answer but if you hope to understand Python "variables" you want to read this: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html